Fedora 40 broken after installing GNU readline
I was developing a program that uses GNU readline library for better input handling. I installed the package and ran the program perfectly. However, I realize that libreadline has a broken linkage.
For example, when I try to commit the code:
git commit -m "commit"
error: gpg failed to sign the data:
/usr/bin/gpg: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.8: undefined symbol: UP

fatal: failed to write commit object

The problem is more than that because libreadline breaks many core util functions such as gpg, awk, gawk, dnf remove in my Fedora machine.
I try to follow some answers from this StackOverflow post. However, none of this works due to the broken commands. make uninstall does not work either because of the previous reason.
Here is my diagnosis so far:
$ gawk --version
gawk: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.8: undefined symbol: UP

$ ldd /bin/gawk
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007f1f3c794000)
        libreadline.so.8 => /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.8 (0x00007f1f3c64d000)
        libmpfr.so.6 => /lib64/libmpfr.so.6 (0x00007f1f3c590000)
        libgmp.so.10 => /lib64/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f1f3c4ec000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1f3c408000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1f3c217000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1f3c796000)

$ ls /usr/lib | grep ncurses
libncurses.so.6
libncurses.so.6.4
libncursesw.so.6
libncursesw.so.6.4

$ ls /usr/local/lib | grep readline
libreadline.a
libreadline.so
libreadline.so.8
libreadline.so.8.2

How can I fix these problems while still able to use readline? Thanks in advance.

readline is part of the distro, why  did you install your own version?

Unfortunately, my system did not include readline. I could not use the headers or the link -lreadline when compiling. So that's why I installed it on my own.

Well, either download it, or update your system as it would be out of date. Fedora does have it.

I am aware of updating my system. Plus, Fedora 40 is not out of date. I stated in my post that libreadline blocks many core functions and commands, including many dnf commands. But thanks anyway.

You are not giving a reason as to why you are not using the supplied version. You are giving the impression that it is a problem with your own built version. Get rid of it & use the supplied one.

Delete what you have in /usr/local/. Then, sudo dnf install readline-devel -- that's where the development headers and other files you need are.
